# How correct find element in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write a custom framework for my autotests, and I'm running into an issue:

login_page_locators.py

```
id_login_input = (By.ID, 'login-input')
```

pages.py

```
import allure
from v2_tests.locators.login_page_locators import *
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver as browser

class LoginPage:
    def click_login_field(self):
        with allure.step(''):
            browser.find_element(*id_login_input).click()
        return self
```

manager.py

```
from v2_tests.pages.login_page import LoginPage

class ClientManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.login_page = LoginPage()

client = ClientManager()
```

and my test_file.py

```
from v2_tests.manager.eo_manager import client

def test_positive_login(open_env):
    client.login_page.click_login_field()
```

when executing the test, I'm seeing:

```
self = 'id', by = 'login-input', value = None
```

screenshot of trouble:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK8a9.png)

How can I successfully locate this element?

Comment: Please read tag descriptions before using tags. From [tag:python-3.x]: "DO NOT USE UNLESS YOUR QUESTION IS FOR PYTHON 3 ONLY. Always use alongside the standard [python] tag."

Comment: You haven't defined a locator with `(By.ID, "login-input")`, only `id_password_input`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that it's a timing issue. I would add a `WebDriverWait` to your click statement.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'password-input'))).click()
```

---

Don't dump all of your locators into `login_page_locators.py`. Don't dump all of your page object classes into `pages.py`. Each website page should have it's own `.py` file and it's own class, e.g. `login_page.py` should contain `class LoginPage` and all locators for the login page should be defined there.

login_page.py

```
import allure
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

class LoginPage:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.password_locator = (By.ID, 'password-input')
        self.driver = driver

    def click_login_field(self):
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        with allure.step(''):
            wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(self.password_locator)).click()
        return self
```

See the Selenium docs on the [page object model](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/test_practices/encouraged/page_object_models). The code samples are Java not python but they will at least give you the basic concepts of how to properly create page objects.

Comment: I did as you advised, but unfortunately the error is the same, I added a screenshot of the error

Comment: I updated my code... I think I fixed the error.

Comment: no, unfortunately something doesn’t work, I copied and pasted your code, but it didn’t help

Comment: Was the error the same? Have you tried something super simple like just code in a single .py file that browses to the site and clicks the element?

Comment: yes, same error. everything works fine if I move the click_login_field() function outside the LoginPage class, then it is possible to click on the element

Comment: So the problem is that you aren't passing the driver into the page object class. I've updated the code and tested it on a different site and it's working.

Comment: omg, i don't understand where i need passing the driver into the page object class, show me please. your example raise error for me

Comment: When you say that my code raises an error but you don't share the error message, it's not terribly helpful. When you instantiate the LoginPage class, you will need to pass in the driver, e.g. `LoginPage()` becomes `LoginPage(driver)`. I don't know where that occurs in your code so you'll have to fix it.

Comment: sorry, i instantiate LoginPage class in manager.py, i update code:
```
from v2_tests.pages.login_page_steps import LoginPage
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver


class ClientManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.login_page = LoginPage(WebDriver)


client = ClientManager()
```

but it still given me erorr from screenshot from question

Comment: I don't know the name of your driver because you don't show that code but it looks like it's `browser` because `browser.find_element()`. If that's the case, the code should be `LoginPage(browser)`.